# WindowsError [error 5] Access is denied

Tags: python, subprocess, windowserror

I'm using the killableprocess package (built on top of subprocess) for running processes
Whenever I run the "killableprocess.Popen(command)" piece of code in my script I get the following error:

```
File "killableprocess.py", line 157, in _execute_child
  winprocess.AssignProcessToJobObject(self._job, hp)
File "winprocess.py", line 37, in ErrCheckBool
  raise WinError()
WindowsError [error 5] Access is denied
Exception TypeError: "'NoneType' object is not callable" in <bound method AutoHANDLE.__del__ of <AutoHANDLE object at 0x025D42B0>> ignored
```

But when I run it from the python interactive console (python 2.6) it works fine.
That probably means there are permission issues when I run this from the script, but I don't know how to solve them. I tried running the script from a cmd that I ran as administrator, but it didn't help.
Tried looking for similar posts but didn't find any good solution. Hope to find some help here
I'm running on Windows, specifically Windows 7 Ultimate x64, if it's any help.

thanks

Answer (score 19):

I solved a similar problem I had by switching to the process directory (I was trying to use inkscape) and it solved my problem

```
import subprocess
inkscape_dir=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Inkscape"
assert os.path.isdir(inkscape_dir)
os.chdir(inkscape_dir)
subprocess.Popen(['inkscape.exe',"-f",fname,"-e",fname_png])
```

Maybe switching to the process directory will work for you too.

Answer (score 10):

What I found when running into this with the subprocess module is that the first entry in 'args' (the first parameter to `subprocess.Popen()`) needed to be just the executable name with no path and I needed to set `executable` in the argument list to the full path of my executable.

```
app = 'app.exe'
appPath = os.path.join(BIN_DIR, app)

commandLine = [app, 'arg1', 'arg2']
process = subprocess.Popen(commandLine, executable=appPath)
```

Comment: Pay attention to the current working directory too; other answers suggest needing to `os.chdir(other_dir)` before starting the process and that may be true depending on the implementation of the process itself. However you can also just use the `cwd=other_dir` argument to `Popen` to set the cwd without needing to change it for the script itself.

Comment: `executable=...` didn't work for me at all, but `os.chdir()` did. `cwd=` works as well and it seems for me to be a nicest answer.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that your paths include the name of the executable file (inkscape.exe)

Comment: very hard to catch this one!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if your module doesn't work, you can use the «subprocess» module:

```
import subprocess, os, time

process = subprocess.Popen("somecommand", shell=True)
n = 0
while True:
    if not process.poll():
        print('The command is running...')
        if n >= 10:
            pid = process.pid
            os.kill(pid, 9) # 9 = SIGKILL
    else:
        print('The command is not running..')
    n += 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Take out the parentheses on `process.pid()` ("TypeError: 'int' object is not callable")

Answer (score 0):

Do you specify *full path* to executable you are passing to `Popen` (the first item in `argv`)?