# Celery on Windows: subprocess.call Access is denied in Celery, runs fine in Django

Tags: python, windows, django, windows-7, celery

I have the following task:

```
@task(track_started = True)
def run_transcode_server():
    commands = ('java', '-cp', settings.TRANSCODE_CLASSPATH, settings.TRANSCODE_JAVA_CLASS)
    subprocess.call(commands)
```

Making the call to subprocess.call directly in the django shell works just fine. However, when celery tries to run that task, it causes this error: `WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied`.

I am running everything under the same user (this is my development environment).

What is causing this? Why can't celery execute subprocesses?

Comment: Do you run Django shell and celeryd from the same user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7130809/1049127

Did you try writing the full path to the Java executable?

Comment: It turns out that I forgot that although the shell works with `java`, when I call it from pythong, I need to call `java.exe`.