# Python script to traverse windows directory and launch app via subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I'm relatively new to python and obviously new to stackoverflow. My goal is to create a file containing information about video files in my library: codecs, size, bitrate, and resolution, that I can easily parse. I plan to use this information to determine which video files are low enough quality to warrant replacement with better-looking encodes.

I found [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) on sourceforge. My script recursively traverses a given directory and calls MediaInfo via subprocess. I resolved an earlier bug thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005437/windowserror-error-5-access-is-denied) thread on stackoverflow describing how to work around Windows permission errors. I also implemented code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006238/how-do-i-hide-the-console-when-i-use-os-system-or-subprocess-call) thread to hide the windows command prompt console, which was instantiated with every call to subprocess.

Currently, my code fails with the following error:
`returned non-zero exit status 1`

The current state of my script is below. Thanks in advance!

```
import os, subprocess
```

I speculate that the issue may lie with how i've formatted the strings which are passed to subprocess

```
types = [".avi", ".mp4", ".mkv"]
app = "MediaInfo.exe"
app_path = os.path.join("C:\Program Files\MediaInfo\MediaInfo_CLI_0.7.61_Windows_x64", app)
movie_dir = "L:\Movies"
current_file = ""
```

The below code launches subprocess without console windows

```
startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
```

Recursively examine directories for media and analyze matching files

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(movie_dir):
    for filename in files:
        for extension in types:
            if (filename.endswith(extension)):
                current_file = '"' + os.path.join(root, filename) + '"'
                output = subprocess.check_output([app, current_file], 
                    executable=app_path, 
                    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                    startupinfo=startupinfo)
                print app_path, current_file, output #debug
                with open("out.txt", "a") as f:
                    f.write(output)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on python 3 (and windows) and above, try using raw strings (or escaping backslashes on windows), OR use forward slashes in forming path! So instead of

```
app = "MediaInfo.exe"
app_path = os.path.join("C:\Program Files\MediaInfo\MediaInfo_CLI_0.7.61_Windows_x64", app)
movie_dir = "L:\Movies"
```

Try using

```
app = r'MediaInfo.exe'
app_path = os.path.join(r'C:\Program Files\MediaInfo\MediaInfo_CLI_0.7.61_Windows_x64',  app)
movie_dir = r'L:\Movies'
```

And similarly ahead also in your script. I have also faced a lot of trouble with spaces in the string 'C:\Program Files..' and by not escaping the backslashes.

Comment: Thanks - raw strings solved my problem. Additionally, I changed the 5th line of the loop `current_file = os.path.join(root, filename)` to reflect that no further modification of the strings was necessary. I also changed the final line `f.write(output.decode())` for Python 3 compatibility.