# Error 5 : Acces is denied when moving files in python

Tags: python

i've been working on a program for a couple of days now, and i'm stuck on a error since last night. I've already looked over other questions here but none seem to work.
I'm moving files from 1 drive to another using shutil, and in the beginning it worked, but now it starts saying this error :

**EDIT:** Just noticed that it does in fact move the files, and after that it gives me the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DC\Desktop\Prototype\Prototype", line 9, in <module>
    shutil.move(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 300, in move
    rmtree(src)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 256, in rmtree
    onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 254, in rmtree
    os.rmdir(path)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'E:'
```

And here's my code snippet.

```
import os
import time

time = time.strftime("%H%M%S")
src = "E:"
dst = "C:\Users\DC\Desktop\Data_" + str(time)

import shutil
shutil.move(src, dst)
print 'Done'
```

Comment: maybe you should check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005437/windowserror-error-5-access-is-denied first.

Comment: DarkTurtle, thanks for the comment, but i had already seen that and cant get any further..

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to move the files from `E:` or the drive itself? :-)

Check if `E:` drive is empty, if it is it means that there's nothing to move. If you want to move the files, not the drive, use a wildcard.

hint: `E:\*.*`

UPDATE:

Linu 82 of shutil.py in the exception you quoted seems to do simple `open` syscall:

```
with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
```

It seems it cannot handle windows drives or patterns like `e:\\*.*`:

```
fo = open(r'D:\*.*','rb')

D:\>python testopen.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testopen.py", line 2, in <module>
    fo = open(r'D:\*.*','rb')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'D:\\*.*'
```

However, for you a very simple workaround would suffice: `os.listdir`.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir('D:\\')
['Videos', 'Pictures', 'Music', 'Documents', ...]
```

`os.listdir` returns a list of files and dirs in a particular dir or windows drive. Once you have a list, do `shutil.move` of each item.

Comment: I am moving from, and there are files, and manually i can just move everything in there.. Thats why i dont really get it

Comment: @user2340383 Try using the wildcard `*` after the drivename as per John's answer.

Comment: I have no access to such Windows machine, so I can only speculate: shutil.move(src) tries to move 'E:' path because that's what you have given it. If there were files in it, it could have moved the files. But now that's empty, it tries to move 'E:' and obviously it can't move drive itself. hence the error. Try smth like "E:\\*.*'

Comment: To be clear, i wanna move the files from E, but i think it moves the files, and then tries to move to drive itself, but that obviously wont work, and i cant seem to figur out the wildcard, it just adds more errors xD

Comment: Sorry for all these problems, but if i change src to src = "E:\*.*", it says thats its an invalid filename (IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'E:\\*.*')

Comment: Are you sure you typed backslash after E: ?

Comment: Yes, it just removes it in the comment, it has  backslash after the E, and in the error it has  backslashes instead of the  shown in the comment

Comment: \ is an escape key, so try `E:\\*.*` instead.

Comment: Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DC\Desktop\Prototype\Prototype", line 10, in <module>
    shutil.move(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 130, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'E:\\*.*'

Answer (score 0):

Please check permissions to `E:\`.

Error shows, user which runs this code snippet, has no permission to `E` drive.

Comment: I am moving from, and there are files, and manually i can just move everything in there.. Thats why i dont really get it  :/